# DoesNotExist at /admin/login/ ---- again?

Tags: django, installation, admin

I've read the old posts with the same title. But the answers are not for my simple case.... But I need your help to be able to move on.

I just installed django 1.8.1, followed the tutorial to the first time hitting url http://localhost:8000/admin

I did have 'django.contrib.admin' in my settings.py, `INSTALLED_APPS` list. Beside that, I haven't done anything about admin.

So what's the problem? how to verify my installation?  Thanks a lot for your help!

(It's ok for the home page http://localhost:8000)

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/login/
Site matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version: 1.8.1
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Site matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 334
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/elim/Projects/python/mydjango',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
Server time:    Tue, 30 Jun 2015 20:37:53 +0000
```

Comment: The problem is right here: `Site matching query does not exist.` Are you using the sites framework? Do you have a `SITE_ID` in your settings?

Comment: attach urls.py file.

Answer (score 1):

If `django.contrib.sites` is in your list of installed apps, then you need `SITE_ID` in your settings file. Adding `SITE_ID = 1` to `settings.py` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe domain name in table django_site not equal your current domain  http://localhost:8000.
You need to open **dango_site** db table and change in first record in field **domain** value to **localhost:8000**

Comment: Can you explain how you would fix the issue?

Comment: Open **dango_site** table and change in first record in field domain value to `localhost:8000`

Comment: I asked to explain for @elim and other people who might read your answer. Not for me :) It would be better to have it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too and as Mikhail suggested, I had a look in django_site db table, and there was an entry with a domain named example.com.
You could change that record to localhost or 127.0.0.1 as Mikhail said, or you could map example.com domain to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts (as I did) and it will solve the problem. If you choose the latter approach, make sure you access the web interface using http://example.com:8000/admin

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean when you say you had a look in django_site db table?